# Using "one can"?

Tags: american-english, pronouns

I can't understand when use "one can" and when just "can". I can't event understand what difference is between them. For example:

> One can smoke on gas station.

Why we need word "one" in this sentence?

Comment: Is your question about the use of **one** vs **you**? "Can smoke in a gas station" is grammatically incorrect.

Comment: @Peter um, does `one` means here any generalized person?

Comment: Yes, some people feel that using **you** is incorrect since it is either too personal or does not mean exactly **you you** but someone in general for which **one** would be more appropriate. **You** is used extensively in AmE and **one** gets used *more so (but not exclusively)* in BrE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because English normally requires you express a subject in every sentence, (even if there isn't a logical subject, as in sentences like "It is raining").

When the subject is a generalised person, people say "you" (more colloquial) or "one" (more formal).

In some very colloquial speech, it is possible to drop the subject when it's obvious who the subject is ("What did you do? Went home"). But I don't think we would ever do this for a generalised subject.